# Where does the extended block in a segwit transaction get stored?

Tags: segregated-witness

I understand where normal blocks get stored. They’re passed along and saved by various nodes. What about the extended blocks of a segwit transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defined in [bip-0141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#Abstract):

> This BIP defines a new structure called a "witness" that is committed
>   to blocks separately from the transaction merkle tree. This structure
>   contains data required to check transaction validity but not required
>   to determine transaction effects. In particular, scripts and
>   signatures are moved into this new structure.
>
> The witness is committed in a tree that is nested into the block's
>   existing merkle root via the coinbase transaction for the purpose of
>   making this BIP soft fork compatible. A future hard fork can place
>   this tree in its own branch.

This new structure represents the extended block which is attached to the merkle root of the coinbase.

If a full node doesn't understand SegWit format it won't be able to validate the transaction. But it can accept it as is, just like lightweight clients do.